# Mongo Update Query is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have the data in one collection in the format given below

```
{
"tenantId":"Hello",
"timings":[{
"name":"Hi",
"category":"standard",
"pickAndPack":30,
"type":"pickup"
},
{
"name":"Hi",
"category":"premium",
"pickAndPack":30,
"type":"pickup"
}]
}
```

I want to update the data inside timings array.But its not working as expected.
Expected Output

```
{
"tenantId":"Hello",
"timings":[{
"name":"Hi",
"category":"standard",
"pickAndPack":30,
"type":"pickup"
},
{
"name":"Hello",
"category":"premium",
"pickAndPack":1200,
"type":"pickup"
}]
}
```

I have tried this query

````
let dataExists = [{
"name":"Hi",
"category":"standard",
"pickAndPack":30,
"type":"pickup"
},
{
"name":"Hello",
"category":"premium",
"pickAndPack":1200,
"type":"pickup"
}

masterdb.collection('corporate').update({ tenantId ,'timings.type': type}, { $set: { 'timings.$': dataExists } });```
````

Comment: Try with this - `var filter = {
 tenantId, 
 timings: {
  $elemMatch: {
   type: type
  }
 }
};

var update = {
 $set: {
  'timings.$': dataExists
 }
};
db.corporate.update(filter, update);`

Comment: I did tried this.But it's not working as expected. It updates the first match.

Comment: Use `{ multi: true }` options

Comment: Yes..It worked for me..Thank you so much